# How to Reset Oracle Optimization for testing proc changes

Tags: oracle

I inherited a proc that takes 90 seconds to run. If I run it again it runs in less than 1 second because Oracle probably saved some optimization stats or something of that nature. I'm not an Oracle guy. So this is making it impossible for me to make changes and see if that speeds up the proc. Is there any way to clear what ever oracle did to optimize this proc? In production it runs too slow, getting lots of complaints.

Comment: Do you suspect that the time difference is caused by Oracle saving input data (so it can read it from memory rather than from disk), or by the query being quite complicated and a lot of time going into parsing and optimization (regardless of the actual execution)? In the first case, you want to flush the buffer cache; in the second, you need to flush the shared pool. (Or you can do both, to be sure.) If you are unfamiliar with these concepts, Google, including for the exact syntax - which is hilariously simple.

Comment: It only has one input and that is a 3 digit region like "021". Its reading from a large table in one of the unions and I suspect it storing some of that table into memory so the second time it draws from memory and not the physical file. the query is not too complicated 4 joins total among two unoins. Ty for the help I will google alter system flush buffer_cache and flush the shared pool

Comment: syntax is ...   alter system flush buffer_cache;
alter system flush shared_pool;

Comment: the reason I suggested Google rather than just telling you the syntax was that I wanted to encourage you to read a little about the concepts to understand what is going on. The "buffer cache" is where Oracle saves data so it doesn't need to read again from disk (apparently what you need). The shared pool is where it stores the executable image of a query, after it has parsed and optimized it and compiled the version it decided is "optimal".

Comment: You may also learn the *beautiful* Oracle trace 10046, where you can exact see what is Oracle doing in the slow and quick executions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two pieces of cache/memory likely involved. The buffer cache and shared pool.

The *buffer cache* is a store of database blocks loaded into memory. When a database block is read from disk, it stays here for a bit. If it can be reused, it's much faster.

The *shared pool* is more complicated (and I don't understand it well), but stores stuff like parsed SQL queries and PL/SQL programs.

If you think your procedure is slow because of one particular query, you can run that query by itself and get an execution plan to figure out why it's slow.

To clear out the stuff that's been loaded into memory, it's two SQL commands:

```
alter system flush buffer_cache;
alter system flush shared_pool;
```